# Coroutine doesn't continue after checking for bool

Tags: unity, coroutines

I have the following coroutine:

```
    public IEnumerator EndGame() {
    //StopAllCoroutines();
    GamePauseController.instance.UnfreezeTime();
    DisintegratorModalController.instance.ignoreBorderDisin = false;
    ignoreBorderEndGame = true;
    StartCoroutine(CubeBehavior.instance.DestroyCubesGameOver());
    StopBackgroundMusic();
    DisableCubeSpawner();
    CubeBehavior.instance.ClearSelectedCubes();
    ScoreManager.instance.StopCountingScore();
    GameDataManager.instance.SaveHighScoreAndDisintegrators();
    ScoreManager.instance.SaveScoreToLeaderboard();
    LightColorManager.instance.WhiteFadeToHeartbeat();

    while (!CubeBehavior.instance.allCubesDestroyed) { // Wait for all the cubes to be destroyed before continuing
        yield return null;
    }

    Debug.Log("Working");
    StartCoroutine(HUDController.instance.HideHUD());
    StartCoroutine(GameResultsController.instance.ShowResultsMenu());
    MenuParticles.instance.Show();
}
```

After the bool check the code below it doesn't execute when it should. What is the issue here?

Comment: When do you expect it to execute?  Using the yield statement will make this function pause, and resume on the next frame.  It will not execute like a standard function.

Comment: Do you call the function by using StartCoroutine(EndGame()) ?

Comment: @Sheikz Yes I did

Comment: `When it should` - you need to tell us what you expect by _when_. We are not psycics. You need to explain how the `allCubesDestroyed` changes, what interacts with them.

Comment: @S.TarıkÇetin The problem is resolved...

Comment: @Milen You are doing same thing again. If it is resolved, write down "how" did you solve it, so people can benefit.

Comment: @S.TarıkÇetin The problem was with another array that prints strings in the game. It's not a general fix, so I can't answer it...

Answer (score 0):

1. `CubeBehavior.instance.allCubesDestroyed` remains `false`.
2. You're calling [`StopAllCoroutines`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopAllCoroutines.html) somewhere else in the code, before this one can complete
3. There's some other error that your code here and explanation haven't revealed.

Attach the debugger, break on execution of the `yield`, check your variables at runtime to ensure they're doing what you expect. Step through your code visually to ensure it's doing what you want. And other basic troubleshooting debugging steps.

Comment: 1. The bool turns to true, I've put a debug log to check that.
2. No other `StopAllCoroutines` in the code save the one I've commented above
3. Not sure about that

Comment: Put a print("Still waiting..."); or something into the while loop just so you can see if it breaks.